# How to already display text in textarea when running file - JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, textarea

I am trying to make it that a user doesn't have to copy and paste a text in the textarea when running the program so instead when running, the textarea already contains the text.My program parses normal text into JSON then into Java,I am trying to make the normal text display in the textarea when starting the program. My code :

**TextArea Code**

```
    private void InputKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String text = "Call me Ishmael. Some years ago-never mind how long precisely-having "
+ "little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, "
+ "I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. "
+ "It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. "
+ "Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, "
+ "drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before "
+ "coffin warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially "
+ "whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral "
+ "principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically "
+ "knocking people's hats off-then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can. "
+ "This is my substitute for pistol and ball. With a philosophical flourish Cato throws himself "
+ "upon his sword; I quietly take to the ship. There is nothing surprising in this. "
+ "If they but knew it, almost all men in their degree, some time or other, cherish "
+ "very nearly the same feelings towards the ocean with me. There now is your insular "
+ "city of the Manhattoes, belted round by wharves as Indian isles by coral reefs-commerce surrounds "
+ "it with her surf. Right and left, the streets take you waterward.";

    Input.setText(text);
}
```

I was unsure in which Event to choose so I just went with KeyPressed. So how can I make the text already appear in the textarea when running the file? Thanks for your time:)

Comment: What exactly does this part of your program do?

Comment: It parses text into json then json into java.

Comment: What do you mean by "when running a file"? Are you reading text from a file and want that displayed in the `textarea`?

Comment: No as you can see by the code its the string text variable.

Comment: If you want this text to appear when "running a file", then why not have the code to set the text inside whatever event is used to initiate "running the file"? Otherwise your question as written doesn't make much sense, and if you still need an answer, you're going to want to improve and expand on your question and problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just simply want to show a text (in the code the long string paragraphs - text) to display in the textarea when running the file, and not have to copy and paste it in the textarea at the start because it is blank. Right now with the code given it just reamins blank and does not show the String text. Hope you understood.

Comment: In your edit you state, `"I am trying to make the normal text display in the textarea when starting the program."` -- then it's simple and there's no need for a key listener. Simply place this text into the JTextArea on program start-up. Done.

Comment: If your question is still unanswered, then create and post a valid [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) -- please read the instructions to be found in these links and follow them. If anything is confusing, then just ask.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That doesn't work, it shows up as blank still when running.

Comment: That is very important key information that you should have told at the start of your question. You've likely got a threading problem.

Comment: See edit for example of what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment:

> it shows up as blank still when running.

Is the key information that you need to give us and suggests that your program is running long-running code on the Swing event thread, and that by doing this, you're preventing the event thread from doing its necessary duties, including drawing the GUI -- including text within the JTextArea, and interacting with the user.

If this is the problem then the solution is to do the long-running code within a background thread, but in doing so, taking care to update the GUI on the event thread only. A SwingWorker could help you do this. [SwingWorker Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RunFile extends JPanel {
    public static final String TEXT = "Call me Ishmael. Some years ago-never mind how long precisely-having "
            + "little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, "
            + "I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. "
            + "It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. "
            + "Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, "
            + "drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before "
            + "coffin warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially "
            + "whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral "
            + "principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically "
            + "knocking people's hats off-then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can. "
            + "This is my substitute for pistol and ball. With a philosophical flourish Cato throws himself "
            + "upon his sword; I quietly take to the ship. There is nothing surprising in this. "
            + "If they but knew it, almost all men in their degree, some time or other, cherish "
            + "very nearly the same feelings towards the ocean with me. There now is your insular "
            + "city of the Manhattoes, belted round by wharves as Indian isles by coral reefs-commerce surrounds "
            + "it with her surf. Right and left, the streets take you waterward.";
    private static final int TXT_AREA_ROWS = 20;
    private static final int TXT_AREA_COLS = 40;
    private JTextArea input = new JTextArea(TXT_AREA_ROWS, TXT_AREA_COLS);

    public RunFile() {
        // put jtextarea into scrollpane and allow wrapping of words
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(input);
        input.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        input.setLineWrap(true);
        input.setFocusable(false);  // make the text area not accept user input

        JPanel bottomButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        // add button that initiates long-running code
        bottomButtonPanel.add(new JButton(new RunFileEvent())); 

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(bottomButtonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    // ActionListener for button that runs long-running code
    private class RunFileEvent extends AbstractAction {
        public RunFileEvent() {
            super("Run File");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_R);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input.setText(TEXT);  // display the text
            setEnabled(false);  // in activate the button

            // create the SwingWorker and start it
            MyWorker myWorker = new MyWorker(this);
            myWorker.execute();
        }
    }

    // SwingWorker to run long-running code
    private class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        private RunFileEvent runFileEvent;

        public MyWorker(RunFileEvent runFileEvent) {
            this.runFileEvent = runFileEvent; // pass button's action into worker
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // simulate a long-running task with a Thread sleep
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            // worker has completed its work
            input.setText("");  // set text area back to empty
            runFileEvent.setEnabled(true);  // re-enable button
            try {
                get();  // call this to capture and handle any exceptions thrown by worker
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RunFile");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new RunFile());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped!